# Neutrino mass difference and mixing angles

Tags: neutrinos

What are the most recent values of the mixing angles associated with the 3 neutrinos flavors and what are their mass differences? Have they been measured in the first place?

Comment: Where have you looked for this information so far?

Comment: @DavidZ google .. I found they measured theta13 .. but couldn't find neither it's value nor any information about the others.. I'm not sure if I'm using the right keywords

Comment: $\theta_{13}$ was the last mixing angle to be measured and is now the most precisely known. Because of the way the mixing angle come into theory they are usually quoted in some power of $sin \theta_{ij}$. The differences of the squared masses are also known. Check with the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) for moderately up-to-date data.

Comment: @dmckee this actually should be an answer.. I found some values in the website!

Comment: The point may be that looking at what the PDG has is the kind of basic research that I, at least, would like everyone to do before asking the site for basic data like this. It's rather like asking the chemistry site for the molar mass of Benzene.

Comment: @dmckee to be honest this is my first time to know about this website. I am an Engineering student and usually when I get stuck in something related to physics I ask here .. thanks